# Error utilizando hooks reactnative, facebook, firebase

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Tengo un problema con react-native, estoy tratando de hacer un login con facebook usando las librerias de expo-facebook y firebase, carga todo bien e inicia sesión bien, pero cuando carga la siguiente pantalla sale lo siguiente:

`Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.`

Adjunto el código donde sucede el login con facebook.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { View, Button, Text, StatusBar, LayoutAnimation, Image, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { Toast } from 'native-base'

import * as Facebook from 'expo-facebook'
import * as firebase from 'firebase'

const app = {
  id: APP_ID,
  name: APP_NAME,
}

export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    header: null,
  }
  facebook = async () => {
    Facebook.initializeAsync(app.id, app.name)
    const { type, token } = await Facebook.logInWithReadPermissionsAsync(app.id, {
      permission: 'public_profile',
    })
    if ( type == "success" ) {
      const credential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential( token )
      firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential)
      .catch(e => {
        console.log(e)
      })
    }
    this.props.navigation.navigate('App')
  }
  render() {
    LayoutAnimation.easeInEaseOut()
    return <View>
        <Button title="Log in with facebook" style={styles.button} onPress={this.facebook}>
        </Button>
      </View>
  }
}
```

Por ultimo adjunto una imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Desconozco mucho esas librerías pero puede ser probable que estén llamando internamente a los hooks, los cuales no se pueden ejecutar dentro de una clase, deberías intentar mover parte de tu lógica a un componente basado en una función, quizá eso te ayude a mitigar el problema

Comment: Ya solucione el problema, el problema era que tenia que crear el store primero y luego ponerlo dentro de la etiqueta Provider

Answer (score 1):

El problema que tienes es que estas usando una version antigua de React exactamente la de React Componentes donde las funciones de react extienden de Component y te esta pidiendo que migres tu aplicación a la version de React Hooks por que ahora para hacer login con Facebook en la version de expo-facebook 7.0.0 o 8.0.0 es necesario usar Hooks.

Te recomiendo que pongas la ultima version de React Native en tu app y uses Hooks para que no tengas ningún problema.

Comment: Siempre uso las ultimas versiones, y ya lo he solucionado gracias, lo solucione declarando las funciones de react redux al inicio del código dentro de uná función la cual es la principal.